# Page is working but showing "Not Secure" sign on browser (configured with Traefik v2 using self-signed cert)

Tags: ssl, https, docker-swarm, traefik

I apologize if this is a silly rookie question, I'm not really experience in dealing with SSL / https so please help me out.

I have docker swarm setup and using Traefik to handle all the HTTPS services. when I first load the page (take grafana page for example), there is a warning page and I click "Advanced" and "Proceed (accept risk)", then the page display and working just fine, the only problem is the "Not Secure" sign showing on browser.
A few things could be contributing to this:

1. Self-created CA and self-signed cert: I'm at development stage so I created my own CA and signed the cert using openssl, and use this cert in Traefik dynamic configuration.

Command to generate CA:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem
```

Command to generate self-signed cert:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out req.pem
openssl x509 -req -in req.pem -days 365 -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out cert.pem
```

See attached screenshot for the errors of the certs: "Subject Alternative Name missing" & "This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)."
[Chrome Dev Tool Certificate Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNFHm.png)

2. Traefik configuration: Not using Let's Encrypt since I don't have an account, so using my own self-signed cert. I don't think this is the issue because I can see the page is using the cert I provided. But if anyone has similar experience with Traefik v2 maybe can give me some pointer if there is anything I set wrong?

Dynamic configuration file that declares the certs:

```
tls:
    stores:
      default:
        defaultCertificate:
          certFile: configuration/cert.pem
          keyFile: configuration/key.pem
```

Question:

1. Is missing SAN a really important factor that will causes my page to be not secure? If yes, how can I add SAN while creating cert with openssl?
2. I understand that 2nd error "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" means browser doesn't recognize the cert's validity. Does that mean I have to install my CA? Where and how to install it? Is it on docker swarm's manager node (this is where Traefik service and the certs at), or is it on any client's machine that trying to access the page?

Comment: The browser does not know your CA so cannot verify the certificate. You should really use a real certificate (there are no Let's Encrypt accounts, just use it). If you really really must, you can add your self-signed CA to your browser (or OS) but it's not recommended at all.

Comment: Hi @Marc, when I first started I follow this tutorial [link](https://containo.us/blog/traefik-2-tls-101-23b4fbee81f1/), I did try out but just couldn't get it work, then I saw that under Option 2 it says "start Traefik with no other configuration than **your Let’s Encrypt account**" so I stop exploring this option.

Comment: "If you really really must, you can add your self-signed CA to your browser (or OS) but it's not recommended at all. "
@Marc, assuming in a scenario where I have a real cert obtaining from one of the certified CA like GoDaddy, do I still need to do this step? And when you say add CA to browser or OS, meaning it is add into whoever's machine that is accessing the webpage, and not adding it into the server where docker swarm is deployed?

Comment: Certficates issued by public CAs (Let's Encrypt, GoDaddy) are already trusted so you don't need to do anything. Only untrusted CAs need to be added, and they would have to be added to the browser of every person that needs to access the site (unless they're happy with an "insecure" button). Given how trivial it is to use Let's Encrypt these days, I recommend doing that.